# strange problem with running bash-scripts from python in docker

Tags: python, bash, docker

I have python-script, which run bash-scripts via subprocess library. I need to collect stdout and stderr to files, so I have wrapper like:

`def execute_chell_script(stage_name, script):
    subprocess.check_output('{} &>logs/{}'.format(script, stage_name), shell=True)`

And it works correct when I launch my python script on mac. But If I launch it in docker-container (`FROM ubuntu:18.04`) I cant see any log-files. I can fix it if I use `bash -c 'command &>log_file'` instead of just `command &>log_file` inside `subprocess.check_output(...)`. But it looks like too much magic.

I thought about the default shell for user, which launches python-script (its root), but `cat /etc/passwd` shows `root ... /bin/bash`.

It would be nice if someone explain me what happened. And maybe I can add some lines to dockerfile to use the same python-script inside and outside docker-container?

Comment: See https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-redirect-command-output-from-docker-container/49758

Comment: Tanvgentially, using `check_output`when you don't get expect any output is weird; and requiring `shell=True` here is misdirected. You want `with open(os.path.join('logs', stage_name)) as output: subprocess.run([script], stdout=ouput, stderr=output)`

Comment: Possibly related, `&>file` is not a [standard POSIX shell redirection operator](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07), so if your `/bin/sh` implements the standard without any vendor extensions (`sh` is not `bash`) you could have trouble.

Comment: @tripleee I rewrote my project to python 3 and used your variant. It looks better and works as I want. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the OP reported in a comment that this fixed their problem, I'm posting it as an answer so they can accept it.

Using `check_output` when you don't get expect any output is weird; and requiring `shell=True` here is misdirected. You want

```py
with open(os.path.join('logs', stage_name)) as output:
    subprocess.run([script], stdout=ouput, stderr=output)
```